# How to externalize javascript in thymeleaf into fragments?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I want to create a reusable javascript fragment that I can then simply include inside `<th:block layout:fragment="script">` blocks, as follows:

```
<th:block layout:fragment="script">
    <div th:replace="test :: script"></div>
</th:block>
```

With `test/script.html`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>
        <div th:fragment="script">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    alert('test alert');
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I directly use the `js` in place of the `th:replace` statement, the alert executes.
When I try to include the fragment as written above, nothing happens.

Question: how can I tell `thymeleaf` to include the externalized js?

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace the outer `<div>` with `<script>`:

<th:block layout:fragment="script">
<**script** th:replace="external :: script">
</th:block>

And also:

<**script** th:fragment="script">